# what is the proper way to catch cookie errors?

Tags: javascript, cookies, try-catch

```
document.cookie =
```

will fire the classic error message "cookie x has been rejected because a non-HTTPS cookie cant' be set as "secure" ..."

OK, but when I try to wrap this using

```
try {document.cookie = ... ;} catch(err) { alert(err.message);}
```

... nothing happens and I still get an error, the alert box does not pop up,
as if   cookie errors   did not raise errors that can be captured by try/catch.

I am puzzled, or what can I do wrong here ?

I expected to have a popup alert message.
Actually I have more serious/useful code to put inside the catch brackets.

Comment: I think the assignment just goes through, without throwing an exception. What you see in the developer console is a warning that your cookie operations didn't do what you expected

Comment: It's important to distinguish errors from warnings. The console shows them differently.